# NoMethodError undefined method `oncreateOptionsMenu` for true:Boolean

Tags: android, ruby, rubymotion

I'm getting the following NoMethodError exception within a very basic RubyMotion app calling `onCreateOptionsMenu` and I'm not sure what is wrong with this.

```
E/com/yourcompany/hello( 5404): Exception raised: NoMethodError: undefined method `onCreateOptionsMenu' for true:Boolean
E/com/yourcompany/hello( 5404):         from main_activity.rb:19 in `onCreateOptionsMenu'
```

This is the RubyMotion method I have defined

```
def onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
  getMenuInflater().inflate(resources.getIdentifier('my', 'menu', 'com.yourcompany.hello'), menu)
  return(super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu))
end
```

I'm also including a working Java equivalent that I created as a comparison, if that is of any help.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.my, menu);
    return(super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Ruby, `super` calls the same method in the parent class.

So this line in your code:

`super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)`

should be just this:

`super(menu)`

Comment: Dude! I can't believe I did something that stupid. I'm using super correctly everywhere else.  Missed that one in my Java to RubyMotion conversion and didn't even notice.  I need more sleep. Thanks!